# (LibGdx) Get mouse position in ENTIRE game

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to get the mouse position IN GAME. By that I mean not the position on the screen, but inside the window. I've been using `Gdx.input.getX()`, but that's not INGAME. How do I do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  What is the difference between in the screen and inside the window?

Comment: I'm getting 2 different positions

Comment: It's not clear what your two different positions are. What are you getting, and what do you want to get instead?  You can edit your question to add more explanation and improve your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Mouse startes at 0,0. My character's x and y are different than the mouses's and i dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **unproject** mouse position in your camera projection matrix.

```
    Vector3 mouse_position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    OrthographicCamera cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2; 
    cam.position.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2;

       ( ... )

    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        cam.update();

            mouse_position.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            cam.unproject(mouse_position);
```

Answer (score 2):

if i get this right, you are trying to get the "game world" pos from screen pos,

as mentioned in their wiki-

```
// x and y are your screen coordinates
 // (e.g. where a click/touch happened)
 Vector3 worldCoordinates = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
 camera.unproject(worldCoordinates);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to substract the viewport's X and Y values to the mouse's coordinates.

```
worldX = mouseX - viewX;
worldY = mouseY - viewY;
```

This way, you won't get the mouse's coordinates relative to the window but relative to the game world.

Comment: What would viewx be?

Comment: is it screen width?

Comment: The on-screen coordinates would be, in that case, the X and Y components of the vector returned by Erez's code. Please look at his answer. His code is more appropriate.